# Recaptcha POST doesn't work with my secret key

Tags: php, post, recaptcha

I have a form for sending email with a recaptcha, everything work when I use test site-key and secret key that I found in the recaptcha faq
[recaptcha faq](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)

But when I insert mine it doesn't work, I,ve tried also to recreate the keys but problem still remain... any suggest?
Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php 
    $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MY_SECRET_KEY&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $responseDecoded  = json_decode($response);
    if ( $responseDecoded->success == false ) {
       echo 'Busted!';
       exit();
    }
    else{
       //here I insert the code for sending email
    }
?>
```

Comment: what error/problem your getting

Comment: I'd be confirming if you can file_get_contents other SSL/HTTPS Links (thinking openssl issue)

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: from the console i get no errors but it still give me "busted!"

Comment: @Scuzzy do you think is beacuse my web site is not on a ssl/https ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here.

```
secret=MY_SECRET_KEY
```

replace `MY_SECRET_KEY` with your actual `secret_key` in `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: I wrote MY_SECRET_KEY for don't share my secret key, but in my file i've insert the correct key

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I've noticed that the snippet for loading the reCaptcha's widget wasn't inside the form but after the closing tag